# Type of "this" keyword?

Tags: java, inheritance, this, static-methods

In Java, "this" refers to the current object. I assumed that "this" is the same type as the current object, but consider this example:

```
class A {
    static void f() {
        System.out.println("A.f");
    }
    void g() {
        this.f();
    }
}
class B extends A {
    static void f() {
        System.out.println("B.f");
    }
}
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B test = new B();
        h(test);
    }
    static void h(B x) {
        x.g();
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
A.f.
```

Which I don't understand, because when x.g() is called, x is of type B. In the x.g() call, g is looked up in B, then in A (because B subclasses A). g then calls f, an instance method of both A and B, meaning that the version of f called depends on the type of the implicit THIS parameter. I would assume that B.f() would be called since X is of type B, but this is not so.

What type does THIS take on, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` methods are not inherited. When you call

```
static void h(B x) {
    x.g();
}
```

You are calling `g()` declared in class `A` which calls

```
static void f() {
    System.out.println("A.f");
}
```

Methods are resolved on the static type of the reference they are called on. For instance methods, polymorphism and late-binding do their trick to execute the actual method. However, since late binding doesn't apply to `static` methods, you are calling `A.f()`.

You can call `static` methods on instance references and they are resolved on their declared type. This is not recommended.

Comment: And that's why you get a compiler warning here.

Comment: I'm confused. This link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10292034/2288418 says all accessible methods are inherited. Besides, if it wasn't inherited, would that result in a compile time error (trying to lookup g in B when x.g()?

Comment: As that answer states, say your child class doesn't declare a `static` method with the same name as a `static` method in the parent class. In this case, because your child class is still the same type as its parent, you can still access the `static` method through a reference or through the class identifier directly.