# Static method call with the class object

Tags: java, static-methods

I have created a class **Check** as a parent class and define one **method as a static** 
and also one more class **Check1** that **extends Check** class now I created a **object** of class **Check1**
and call the Check class method with this object and its work properly.
How can it would be possible ? because static method of class work only with the name of class .

**Check class:**

```
public class Check
{
  static void main(int a[])
  {
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i] + "\t");
    }   System.out.println();
  }
}
```

**Check1 class:**

```
public class Check1 extends Check
 {

public static void main(String a[])
{
    Check1 ob=new Check1();
    int a1[]={1,2,3,4};
    ob.main(a1);                    // working
    main(a1);                      // working
    Check.main(a1);                 // working
    Check1.main(a1);                // working
    System.out.println("Main");
}
}
```

give me a solution or am I doing wrong in my program?

Comment: You can also do it with null object because static method checks class not object such as `Check c=null; c.main(a1);`. There is no null pointer exception in this case.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, or even what's not working. But your object has the same name as your class, so an object method call would look exactly like a static call.

Comment: You are overriding the `main()` method. You don't always have to put the name of the class in front. You can also just call it by name from within the class. I'm pretty sure when you use `Check1.main()` you will get a stack overflow, because  you are causing infinite recursion!

Comment: This may help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java

Answer (score 0):

`static` methods are inherited just like any other method, and can be overridden just like any other method. `static` simply implies that the method isn't bound to an instance of a class, but the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

I hope when you see this example you will understand about static

```
public class Animal
{
    public static void hide() 
    {
        System.out.format("The hide method in Animal.%n");
    }
    public void override()
    {
        System.out.format("The override method in Animal.%n");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
    public static void hide() 
    {
        System.out.format("The hide method in Animal.%n");
    }
    public void override()
    {
        System.out.format("The override method in Animal.%n");
    }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     Animal a = new Dog();
     a.hide();
     a.override();
   }
}
```

In simpler terms, instance methods are overridden and static methods are hidden.

Thank you.