# How do you design one screen to handle many (similar, subclassed) objects?

Tags: java, inheritance, static

Preface: I am trying to solve my problem without the need for boilerplate code. I could easily solve this problem by copy/pasting and refactoring code, but this kind of problem should be solvable with a model-driven approach because of the obvious recurrence of the design.

I have a database application with four different object types that will be used as parameters for another, central object.

[image]

All four fields are structurally the same: one auto-generated primary key, and one `VARCHAR` field. These fields need to be editable by the end-user, so I designed this screen:

[image]

Rather than making four different screens for this, I thought it would be good to make this one screen that is used by the four different object types. To accomplish this, I (obviously, right?) need to make an abstract Object (what I called) `StringField` which can be implemented by four subtypes: `Status`, `Type`, `Classification`, and `Designation`. As mentioned before, because every object is structurally identical and will read/write to the database the same exact way, an abstract object seemed logical. So, I made this object:

```
public abstract class StringField {

    private final int id;
    private final String value;
    private final String fieldname;
    private final String tablename;

    public StringField(int id, String value, String fieldname, String tablename) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
        this.fieldname = fieldname;
        this.tablename = tablename;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 59 * hash + this.id;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.id == ((StringField)obj).id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

    public int insertValue(DB db, String value) throws WrappedSQLException {

        ... // DB code here
    }

    public void updateValue(DB db, String value, int id) throws WrappedSQLException {

        ... // DB code here
    }

    public void deleteValue(DB db, int id) throws WrappedSQLException {

        ... // DB code here
    }
}
```

With subclasses implementing as follows (for example):

```
public class Type extends StringField {

    public Type(int id, String value) {
        super(id, value, "type", "customer_type");
    }
}

public class Classification extends StringField {

    public Classification (int id, String value) {
        super(id, value, "classification", "customer_classification");
    }
}
```

> An aside: the reason for `String fieldname` and `String tablename` in
>   the constructor is that Java does not allow for static abstract
>   fields. So, they'll need to be supplied manually by the classes which
>   use the super type. This, unfortunately, prevents the `insert`,
>   `update`, and `delete` methods from being declared `static` as well.
>   If Java allowed `static abstract`, I doubt I'd be asking this question
>   at all because I would just make the `insert`, `update`, and `delete`
>   methods static with `fieldname` and `tablename` as abstract static
>   fields, which would be forced to be implemented by the subtypes in
>   static fashion and could then be referenced statically by the
>   superclass, which could then be called statically through each
>   subtype. Basically, it could look like this:
>
> Supertype:
>
> ```
> public abstract class StringField {
>
>     private final int id;
>     private final String value;
>
>     public StringField(int id, String value) {
>         this.id = id;
>         this.value = value;
>     }
>
>     public static abstract String fieldname;
>     public static abstract String tablename;
>
>     public static int insertValue(String value) {
>
>         // Insert code, returns auto-generated primary key
>         // ...
>         // This code will use the static fields `fieldname` and `tablename`.
>         // ...
>         return -1;
>     }
>
>     public static void updateValue(String value, int id) {
>
>         // Update code...
>         // ...
>         // This code will use the static fields `fieldname` and `tablename`.
>         // ...
>     }
>
>     public static void deleteValue(int id) {
>
>         // Delete code...
>         // ...
>         // This code will use the static fields `fieldname` and `tablename`.
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Subtype:
>
> ```
> static class Type extends StringField {
>
>     public Type(int id, String value) {
>         super(id, value);
>     }
>
>     public static String fieldname = "type";
>     public static String tablename = "customer_type";
> }
> ```
>
> And used like:
>
> ```
> Type.insertValue(newValue);
> ```

Ok, enough complaining about how Java doesn't allow `static abstract`. Here is the full, (almost) compile-able code I have so far that illustrates my approach:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StringFieldEditor extends JPanel {

    final Collection<StringField> fields;
    String fieldname;
    public StringFieldEditor(Collection<StringField> fields, String fieldname) {
        super(new GridBagLayout());
        this.fields = fields;
        this.fieldname = fieldname;
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        JButton addNew_button = new JButton();
        JButton delete_button = new JButton();
        JButton edit_button = new JButton();
        JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
        JList<StringField> jList = new JList<>();
        jList.setModel(new DefaultListModel<>());
        jList.setListData(fields.toArray(new StringField[fields.size()]));
        JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList);

        jLabel1.setText("Customer " + fieldname + " Editor");
        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(11, 10, 0, 0);
        add(jLabel1, gridBagConstraints);


        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 5;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 178;
        gridBagConstraints.ipady = 206;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(6, 10, 0, 10);
        add(jScrollPane1, gridBagConstraints);

        addNew_button.setText("Add New");
        addNew_button.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
            // Add New Task
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(6, 10, 11, 0);
        add(addNew_button, gridBagConstraints);

        edit_button.setText("Edit");
        edit_button.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
            // Edit Task
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 3;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(6, 6, 11, 0);
        add(edit_button, gridBagConstraints);

        delete_button.setText("Delete");
        delete_button.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
            // Delete Task
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(6, 6, 11, 10);
        add(delete_button, gridBagConstraints);
    }

    static class Type extends StringField {

        public Type(int id, String value) {
            super(id, value, "type", "customer_type");
        }
    }

    public abstract class StringField {

        private final int id;
        private final String value;
        private final String fieldname;
        private final String tablename;

        public StringField(int id, String value, String fieldname, String tablename) {
            this.id = id;
            this.value = value;
            this.fieldname = fieldname;
            this.tablename = tablename;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 5;
            hash = 59 * hash + this.id;
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            return this.id == ((StringField)obj).id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }

        public int insertValue(String value) {

            // Insert code, returns auto-generated primary key
            // ...
            // ...
            return -1;
        }

        public void updateValue(String value, int id) {

            // Update code...
            // ...
            // ...
        }

        public void deleteValue(int id) {

            // Delete code...
            // ...
            // ...
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Type> types = new LinkedList<>();
        types.add(new Type(1, "Type 1"));
        types.add(new Type(2, "Type 2"));
        types.add(new Type(3, "Type 3"));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new StringFieldEditor(types, "type"));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This, however, throws an error:

```
incompatible types: LinkedList<Type> cannot be converted to Collection<StringFieldEditor.StringField>
```

But changing:

```
    final Collection<StringField> fields;
    String fieldname;
    public StringFieldEditor(Collection<StringField> fields, String fieldname) {
```

to

```
    final Collection<? extends StringField> fields;
    String fieldname;
    public StringFieldEditor(Collection<? extends StringField> fields, String fieldname) {
```

causes issues when trying to load the data into the `JList` (`toArray` requires a type `T` value, but if I don't know the exact type I'm working with, I can't supply it a new `T` type array.

Also, I forsee the problem of trying to reference the non-static insert, update, and delete methods in a non-subclass specific way.

My questions:

1. Is this approach viable? Am I taking this whole model-driven development approach too far?
2. Is there a better way to achieve this functionality without creating boilerplate code?
3. Is there a good workaround to the fact that there are no `static abstract` methods/fields in Java for this?
4. Is there a way to supply the `Collections::toArray(T[])` method a usable array when you don't know which subtype you'll be using?