# Invoking main() method from parent class

Tags: java, program-entry-point

There is a code:

```
class Test1{
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        System.out.println("Test1");
    }
}

class Test2 extends Test1{
}
```

When I try to execute `java Test1` I'm getting, of course, this:

> Test1

But, when I try to execute `java Test2` I'm still getting:

> Test1

Why? In class Test2 doesn't exist main() method. And static methods don't inherited. If I'll add main() in Test2 (with string "Test2" instead of "Test1") I'll get:

> Test2

I understand why I'm getting Test2 in this example. But don't understand why I'm getting Test1 if main() doesn't exist in class Test2.

Comment: `And static methods don't inherited.` Who told you that? Static methods can't be **overridden** (they are not polymorphic), but they can be *inherited* and *shadowed* like you see clearly in your example.

Comment: @KlemensMorbe now that's a lie.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are static methods inherited in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java)

Comment: When classloader can't find main() method in class, does he search main() method in parent classes?

Comment: My previous comment has error: static methods are *hidden*, not *shadowed*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And static methods don't inherited.

Static methods are inherited. Take a look at [jls-8.4.8 Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8)

> A class C inherits from its direct superclass and direct superinterfaces all `abstract` and `non-abstract` methods of the superclass and superinterfaces that are `public`, `protected`, or declared with `default` access in the same package as C, and are neither overridden (§8.4.8.1) nor hidden (§8.4.8.2) by a declaration in the class.

There is no information about not inheriting static methods, which is why you can run `main` declared in `Test1` via `Test2` class (it was inherited).

---

Also from [jls-8.4.8.2  Hiding (by Class Methods)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2)

> If a class declares a `static` method `m`, then the declaration `m` is said to **hide** any method `m`', where the signature of `m` is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of `m`', in the superclasses and superinterfaces of the class that would otherwise be accessible to code in the class.

So when you created new `main` method in `Test2` class you hidden (not overridden) `Test1.main` method which is why you saw as output

```
Test2
```

Comment: Thank you. If i understand correctly, when creating Class-object, Test2 inherits static method main() from Test1. And if don't create it explicitly, then will invoked inherited method.

Answer (score 2):

Static methods do in fact get inherited. That's what's happening here. Ex. this works just fine:

```
class Base {
    public static void saySomething() {
        System.out.println("Hi!");
    }
}

class Extended extends Base {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        saySomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, now it isn't important. I try to understand why was invoked method in parent class instead of error.

Comment: Why would you expect an error? The JVM looked for a main method in the inheritance tree of Test2 and found one.

Comment: At the time of writing the commentary I wasn't understanding this. :)