# Which members are not inherited in a child class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, subclass

I'm trying to answer the following question:

> A child class would not inherit certain members of the parent class. Name three
>       such members.

I know private members are not inherited to child classes and default members are not inherited outside of the package. Can anyone complete the answer?

Edited:-
I believe that static members are inherited according to below demonstration

```
public class sup {
    public static void main(String agr[]){
    }

    protected static int staticInt=0;
    protected final int finalInt=3;
    protected int protectedInt=0;
    public String publicString = "";
    private int privateInt=8;
}

class sub extends sup{
    public void del(){
        staticInt=1;
        staticInt=finalInt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None-Answer to make a case for *terms* usage.

Members which are **visible** in the child class is answered above. **Members** being both fields and methods (each having its own namespace).

**Inheritance** as being *part of the child instance*, is another question: also invisible *private* members are "inherited" as such. *Static* members are part of the class instance and are not inherited (cannot be overriden too). All *final* methods cannot be overriden.

Arguable constructors are not inherited; you have to define the same signature again in a new child constructor.

Other declarations in a class could be class definitions. There the keyword `static` has a different meaning, and one may make obvious statements on visibility/inheritance. For instance with respect to non-static inner classes, which have an `<outer-class>.this` (recursive notion).

Answer (score 6):

from [JLS for Class Member](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2)

> Constructors, static initializers, and instance initializers are not members and therefore are not inherited.

Comment: Ding ding ding! Finally, the correct answer and from the JLS too :-)

Comment: @Duncan o darn! :) this is indeed the *fully* correct answer. how did i miss that... +1

Answer (score 3):

from Oracle Java Documentation for [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) :

> A subclass inherits all the members (fields, methods, and nested
>   classes) from its superclass. **Constructors** are not members, so they
>   are not inherited by subclasses, but the constructor of the superclass
>   can be invoked from the subclass

So I think you're missing constructors here . 
Static Methods and fields are not inherited too, when they are rewritten in subclasses, they just reuse the signature and `hide` the  implementation of the method/field in the parent class.

For Inheritance of static fields and methods, refer to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java) as steted by Duncan, and this great tutorial [Overriding vs Hiding](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/OverridingVsHiding)

Comment: See this discussion too: [Are static methods inherited in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java). This disagrees with your final paragraph.

Comment: @Duncan Thank you man !! I've just discovered the difference between Overriden and Hidden :)

Answer (score 1):

Constructors and static initializers and instance initializers.

Comment: Can you explain why static members are not inherited? I guess it's a terminology thing, there are some subtle differences between static and instance methods as discussed here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: static members are inherit. I test it using sample program

Comment: Are you talking about visibility ? inheritance and visibility are two different things. static members may visible but can't override them.

Comment: @Eugene I'm still not convinced that you can say static methods aren't inherited. Do you have any sources to cite where that is explicitly stated?

Comment: @Duncan I don't get it. The tutorial clearly says that static methods are not inherited and they do *hide*. I don't think that's a JLS thing..

Comment: @Eugene There is no statement that I've seen that says "static methods are not inherited". I think you may be mistaken - see this question for example: [Are static methods inherited in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-in-java) and also [mounaim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23103694/474189).

Comment: @Duncan no, I'm not. I'm just saying that since they say that static methods hide the one in the superclass, it must mean that it is not inherited. I do agree that this is not stated per se; but it is auto-implied, at least for me.

Comment: @Eugene You seem to be thinking that inheritance is synonymous with the ability to override. I don't think that's correct.

Comment: @Eugene See example 8.2-3 from the JLS (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2). This states that the static field is inherited.

Answer (score 0):

you can't inherit a private field,and constructor.
you can't inherit a constructor because they are not member of super class. you can invoke a super class constructor form it's sub class. and you can also access a private member of super class can be accessed through public or protected method of super classes.

Comment: -1 Static members are inherited. See discussions under the other answers.