# Java: Use Static methods of Parent Class in Child Class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, static-methods

I'm trying to refactor my code by using a `BaseComponentType` class and inheriting from this in my `ElectricalComponentType` class *(and similar child classes)*, as follows:

#### BaseComponentType.java

```
public abstract class BaseComponentType {

    public static BaseComponentType findByUid ( Class klass, String uid ) {

        return new Select().from( klass ).where( "uid = ?", uid ).executeSingle();

    }

}
```

#### ElectricalComponentType.java

```
public class ElectricalComponentType extends BaseComponentType {

    public static ElectricalComponentType findByUid( String uid ) {

        return (ElectricalComponentType) findByUid( ElectricalComponentType.class, uid );

    }

}
```

What I need to do is call `ElectricalComponentType.findByUid( 'a1234' )` but it would be great if I did not have to define `findByUid` in the `ElectricalComponentType` class and instead could inherit this functionality from the `BaseComponentType`.

You'll notice that two things stand in the way:

1. I need the `ElectricalComponentType` class in the `findByUid` parent method.
2. I need to return `ElectricalComponentType` object (or whatever the child class object is) instead of a `BaseComponentType` class object.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'remove' the findByUid method? You can't just delete that? And your abstract class does not seem to have any abstract methods, so you don't 'have to' override anything. What is the motive here?

Comment: If you don't need the findByUid method in your ElectricalComponentType, then why did you program it there? I daresay the best way to remove it is never have programmed it in the first place.

Comment: You may want to take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java or at any of the other ones on the right that talk about static methods and inheritance.

Comment: By "remove", I mean that I would like to not have to **define** it in the `ElectricalComponentType` model, but I still need to do `ElectricalComponentType.findByUid( 'a433' )`. I'll update the question a little bit.

Comment: @JoshPinter You're not required to override any methods except the abstract ones (which you didn't define in the sample).

Comment: @JoshPinter Why do you want findByUid() to be static? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mttdbrd This is essentially finding an object from the database. It makes sense to me to use `ElectricalComponentType.findByUid('a1234')` instead of `new ElectricalComponentType().findByUid('a1234')`, don't you agree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use generics and only have the parent class method:

```
public abstract class BaseComponentType {
    public static <T extends BaseComponentType> T findByUid(Class<T> klass, String uid) {
        return new Select().from( klass ).where( "uid = ?", uid ).executeSingle();
    }
}
```

Comment: So the formatting of this is pretty special, requiring `<T extends BaseComponentType> T`. Do you have a link I can read up on this more?

Comment: Glad you like it. For more info, start with [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). If you need more google "java generic methods" or "java typed methods"

Comment: Thanks. One last thing, is it possible to determine the child class programmatically so I can remove the `Class<T> klass` function param?

Comment: If the `from()` method requires a `class` object of type `T` (which is highly likely), then "no" there is no way to avoid passing the `class` object, because due to runtime type erasure you can't create a `class` object of type `T` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There are several points to note:

- `static` methods are not being inherited and cannot be overriden;
- To call `static` method of your parent class, you have to write class name first: `BaseComponentType.findById()`;

If you want to get rid of method with the same name in child class, you may want to make it non-static or/and reconsider your classes design, because if you have two static methods with the same names in classes bound with inheritance relation, most likely there is something wrong with class design.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you need something like following..

```
public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Child c2;
        c2 = (Child) Child.findByUid(Child.class, "123");
        System.out.println(c2.getClass());
    }            
}

class Base{
    public static Base findByUid ( Class klass, String uid ) {
        System.out.println(klass);
        Child c = new Child();
            //execute your query here and expect it to return the type of object as the class by which it was called
        //your parent class method always returns the type of the child by which the method was called
        return c;

    }

}

class Child extends Base{
    /*public static Child findByUid( String uid ) {
        System.out.println(Child.class);
        return (Child) findByUid( Child.class, uid );

    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could reengineer this so that you have a `ComponentFinder` class that finds `Component`s.

```
public class ElectricalComponent extends Component {

     @Override
     public void method1(){
         //specific stuff
     }

}

public abstract class Component{
     public abstract void method1();
}

public class ComponentFinder{

    public static Component findByUid ( Class klass, String uid ) {

        return new Select().from( klass ).where( "uid = ?", uid ).executeSingle();

    }

}
```

Then you don't have to worry about the inheritance issue.