# why we cannot override private and final methods?

Tags: java, private, final

Why we can make a method of same signature as a private method but we can not override it

I am no understanding why we cannot override a private method but we can make another method of same signature
I think that they are the same.

Comment: The reason you mark a method `final` in the first place is to stop it being overridden - that's exactly what it's designed to do.

Comment: `final` is just *designed* for preventing the method to be overriden and as for `private` the derived class has *no access* to such methods.

Comment: @JonK i now that we cannot override private and final method but my professor said that we can make the same method with the same signature yet this is not overriding. and i do  not understand this.

Comment: Overloading a method is creating a new method with a different signature.  It's like asking why can I create two method which start with the same letter (in this case the signature starts with the same word)

Answer (score 4):

The `final` keyword is meant to forbid anyone from overriding a method. You can mark a method as final if your class depends on the specific implementation of that method, to prevent other code from breaking your class.

A private method is only visible to the class to which it belongs. Therefore subclasses cannot override a private method: the subclass is not aware that a method of the same signature already exists in a superclass.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this can explain it

You have two classes `StackOverflow` and `A` that extends StackOverflow

You see how both classes have the same `private String myStackOverflow()` signature?

This method is independent on each class and it can not be accessed outside of their own class (thus the `private` keyword).

That is not the case with `hello()` which is `public`

Class `A` can see it (because is an extension of `StackOverflow`), and may (or may not) override it.

```
public class StackOverflow {

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello: " + myStackOverflow());
    }

    private String myStackOverflow() {
        return "Welcome to StackOverflow";
    }

    public class A extends StackOverflow{

        @Override
        public void hello() {
             System.out.println("Hi, how are you? " + myStackOverflow());
        }

        private String myStackOverflow() {
            return "I hope you like your stay on StackOverflow";
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the excellent explanation appreciated can you please explain for me why static methods also cannot be overloaded and are they   inherited??

Comment: @SaraChatila [This Anwser explains static method inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java)