# Static method from superclass called on subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, static-methods

I need to call a superclass static method on a subclass and be aware that it was called on a subclass. The following code shows the use case, please notice the method invocation on a subclass `B.importantMethod()` and the place where I need to know that it was called on subclass: `//would like to get B here`.

```
class A {
    public static void importantMethod() {
        System.out.println("???"); //would like to get B here
    }
}

class B extends A {
    //no implementation, just inheritance
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B.importantMethod();
    }
}
```

Any possible way of achieving this will be good for me. My tries ended up with nothing, I always get `A`, not `B`.

Comment: Well that seems like a very bizarre thing to do. What is that you want to solve - maybe we can help you find a better way to do it.

Comment: You can probably do this using Groovy, in which you can write pure Java, but not with Java

Answer (score 2):

This is just not possible. Static methods always belong to the class that defines them. `importantMethod` is a method of class `A`.

Answer (score 1):

static methods are class methods and thus belong to that class; there is no way to do what you want. For a further explanation, see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java).
If you provide more information about the problem you are trying address this way, may be we can help you find an alternative solution.