# Accessing superclass static method in subclass

Tags: java, static-methods

Since a static method is restricted to a class only why is the subclass using the static method of the superclass in the below code?

```
public class StaticMethodEg extends Superclass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(StaticMethodEg.MyStaticMethod(2313123));
    }
}

class Superclass {
    public static int MyStaticMethod(int i) {
        Integer value = new Integer(i);
        return value + 1234;
    }
}
```

output

```
2314357
```

Comment: ***extends Subclass*** dear God why?

Comment: sorry wrong program...corrected it

Answer (score 2):

Static methods are inheritable but not overridable.
So, the subclasses see the public static method of the parent class.

`StaticMethodEg.MyStaticMethod(2313123)` is legal but is is really misleading as it could give the impression that the `StaticMethodEg` class have a `MyStaticMethod(int)` that hides the static method of the parent. But it is not the case.

`Superclass.MyStaticMethod(2313123)` is clearer.

Comment: Ohk means what i did is applicable but should not be valid...and also further proceeding i found that subclass which extends StaticMethodEg class also prints MyStaticMethod(2313123); method.Mean subclass of subclass also prints method of superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not compiling

```
 System.out.println(StaticMethodEg.MyStaticMethod(2313123));
```

you have to do

```
System.out.println(Superclass.MyStaticMethod(2313123));
```

> Since static method is restricted to class only...

not really, the method is public so the **StaticMethodEg** class has access to that method too!

Answer (score 0):

No, a **`public`** `static` method can be used anywhere, not only in the class it was declared in.

`static` methods are also inherited (like non-static methods), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java) for more information. In your case `MyStaticMethod` is inherited by `StaticMethodEg` class, as it `extends Superclass` .