# Why does my static block allows to call parent class static method without using parentclass reference?

Tags: java, static-methods, static-block

From what I understand, usually the static method should be called using class's reference or it can be called directly without reference if its in a static method or static block.

But does this apply when static method is called from child class static blocks?

Why it allows such thing, as static methods are not inherited, it should only be allowed using parent class name right?

```
public abstract class abs {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    abstract void m();
    static void n(){
        System.out.println("satic method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
class myclass extends abs{

    @Override
    void m() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    static{
        n();
    }
}
```

Why my child class static block can call parent class static method without reference or classname?

Comment: Static methods are inherited.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10292034/2557030) about static method inheritance in Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static method `n()` is inherited by subclass `myclass`, so you can call it directly in the static block of `myclass`.

Comment: doesnt it violate the whole concept of "static belongs to class hence cannot be inherited" ?

Comment: @amarnathharish [Are static methods inherited in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10291949), especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/29725529/1393766

Comment: "The only difference with inherited static (class) methods and inherited non-static (instance) methods is that when you write a new static method with the same signature, the old static method is just hidden, not overridden."   this makes sense

Comment: @amarnathharish There is no such concept. You are mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

> Usually the static method should be called using class's reference or
>   it can be called directly without reference if its in a static method
>   or static block.

Not really. For example an instance method can invoke a static method without prefixing the class.

More generally, `static` members (fields as methods) have to be invoked by prefixing their class only as the compiler cannot infer the class where they belong to.
As you invoke a static method defined in the parent class from a subclass (and static methods are inherited in the subclasses), you don't need to prefix the class of the method invocation as the compiler infer that.

Comment: okay i have one question, if static methods are inherited what if i also have another static method in the childclass with same method signatures ? how will the compiler resolve that?

Comment: In this case, the method defined in the subclass shadows (and not overrides) which one defined in the parent. Note that it is generally a bad practice. Without any prefix, in the class context the compiler will choose the method of the current class.

Answer (score 0):

Because you inherited the parent class, you have access to all non private members of that class directly as if it belonged to the child class.

Answer (score 0):

> Why it allows such thing

By inheritance.

> as static methods are not inherited

You keep saying that. You're mistaken. From [JLS #8.4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8):

> A class C inherits from its direct superclass all concrete methods m (both `static` and instance) of the superclass for which all of the following are true: ...

For continuation see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29725529/207421).

Answer (score -1):

All the members of superclass are inherited by subclass, which includes static methods too.

```
    class SuperClassA {

    static void superclassmethod() {
        System.out.println("superclassmethod in Superclass ");
    }
}

public class SubClassA extends SuperClassA {
    static {
        superclassmethod();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

But when a static method of superclass is override it hides the superclass static method not overrides it.

Comment: There is no such thing as overriding of static methods.

Comment: @ EJP                                                                                            What I meant was if one writes in subclass a static method with the same name as that of the static method existing in superclass, then in this case the subclass method is not overriding the superclass static method but it hides the superclass static method. And also the runtime Polymorphism does not get applied when it is static method.