# How use static extended variables in Java?

Tags: java, static-methods, static-variables

We have `base` class as follow:

```
public class Base {
    protected static string rule = "test_1";

    public static getRule(){
    /* get rule value from origin class*/
    }
}
```

We have some classes that extend from `base` class. For example:

```
public class Derived extends Base {
     static {
          rule = "test_2";
     }
}
```

Now we wants to get rule variable, but in some conditions:

- If user call `Derived.getRule()`, it return `test_2`,
- If in `derived` class `rule` variable not init, it returned `test_1`,
- I don't want to override `getRule` in all subclasses for answer the question.

**What do I do?**

Comment: Static methods and fields are not subject to overriding. If you have an instance method in your base class, you can override it to return different things in your derived classes. But if you actually want to call `Derived.getRule()` directly on the `Derived` class, you can just define a static method `getRule()` in `Derived`.

Comment: Define a method called `getRule()` in `Derived` which hides `getRule` in base. But this seems like a generally ill-advised design.

Comment: You may not use static, they have to be used in very specific cases, think about your model

Comment: @azro Can you take an example?

Comment: @MortezaMalvandi I don't know what your doing. And you can just make a getRule method in each and like  return "test_2", or define the rule variable in each

Comment: Basically, **don't** imagine that inheritance works for static stuff. You can even create a totally non-related class and create a static getter that gets `rule` from `Base`, and a setter that sets the `rule` from `Base`. In short, the word `extends` means *nothing* in this context, except that `rule` in the inherited class automatically points to `rule` in direct super class, unless there is already one in the current class.

Comment: Some reading: [Are static methods inherited in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that once the `Derived` class is used (initialized), `Base.rule` is changed, and everywhere now `test_2` is returned, irrespective of the actual class.

So the technique has to be done without static (in that form). There is a categorical, class level value.

```
public class Base {
    private static final String BASE_RULE = "test_1";

    public String getRule() {
        return BASE_RULE;
    }
}

public class Derived extends Base {
    private static final String DERIVED_RULE = "test_2";

    @Override
    public String getRule() {
        return DERIVED_RULE;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use marker interfaces - which are not mutual-exclusive however, hence not for some getCategory().

```
public class Base implements Test1Category {
}

public class Derived extends Base implements Test2Category { ... }

if (base instanceof Test2Category) { ... }
```