# Accessing static constants from a parent class

Tags: java, static

*(Context: I'm coming from a Python world and just re-learning my way around Java.  Go gentle on me!)*

Imagine I'd like the following effect from my Java program:

```
> SpacelySprockets.getName() => "Spacely Sprockets, Inc."
> CogswellCogs.getName() => "Cogswell Cogs Corp."
```

I know the following isn't legal Java, but I'd imagine a structure along these lines:

```
public class Manufacturer {
    public static String getName() { return COMPANY_NAME; }
}
public class SpacelySprockets extends Manufacturer {
    public static String COMPANY_NAME = "Spacely Sprockets, Inc.";
}
public class CogswellCogs extends Manufacturer {
    public static String COMPANY_NAME = "Cogswell Cogs Corp.";
}
```

(FWIW: In a Python program, when the classmethod `getName()` function is executed, it has access to the calling class's bindings i.e. `COMPANY_NAME`).  So:

- Is something along these lines legal in Java?
- If so, what's the correct syntax and/or idiom?

Comment: Does this help? [Are static methods inherited in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291949/are-static-methods-inherited-in-java)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) . Do you have a higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Turing85: Higher level problem: Yes -- USB devices.  Before I have an instance of the USB device, I have static methods that can query the HW.  I need configure the HW before I can instantiate the object, thus the static method.  For now, I'm passing the `COMPANY_NAME` (or equiv) as a parameter to the config function.  Works, but that means I need to create an identical function in each subclass.  That feels wrong.

Comment: Java static methods aren’t really class methods. Using an instance method seems better. Maybe you are reinventing enums?